# Putative correspondences

Tags: matlab, image-processing, correspondence

I am trying to implement the algorithm for estimating the fundamental matrix between two images using RANSAC. So far I have found the interest points using Harris corner detection. I am stuck at computing the putative correspondences using these interest points. I don't want to use matlab toolbox for that , I like to know a way to learn about corresponding point extraction from two images and it's implementation. I have read about block matching but have not completely understood the concept of it. Any samples and guidelines would help me to understand this problem better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to search for corresponding interest points, but they're usually based on describing each of these interest points using the characteristics of the image around them, and, for each point in one image, comparing its surrounding's characteristics to the characteristics of the surroundings of other interest points in the other image.

Now assume you've decided to consider only a squared region (a block) around each point of interest that contains the intensity values of the image around the point. Now you can compare these blocks, and match those that are close to each other. The problem is now how to define "close" or, in other words, how to define the distance metric you'll use to compare these blocks.
There are many approaches, for example, you could use the sum-of-absolute-differences between two blocks, which means you could subtract two blocks, take the absolute value of the resulting block, and then sum all values in this resulting block, obtaining a scalar value which represents how close these blocks are. If this distance is less than a given threshold, you can consider the two blocks a match. This is basically what block matching does.

Similarly, you could define other types of regions to describe your points of interes, for example by changing their shapes, sizes, orientations etc, and create more complex descriptors for these points of interest, which might capture more distinguishable characteristics (which is highly desired if you have the purpose of matching them later).

If you want to learn more about the topic, I think this presentation can get you started:
http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse455/09wi/Lects/lect6.pdf